# c# delegate declared without a complete statement

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a delegate

```
public delegate object ABC(object a);
```

i have some other class that wants to do

```
new Dictionary<string,object>(){

{"key1",delegate(object val){return "blah"}},

{"key2",delegate(object val){return "blah2"}}};
```

The problem is if I don't declare the delegate ahead of time like this

```
ABC del = delegate(object val){return "blah"};
```

and then stick del inside my dictionary, it won't compile because the use of ABC there somehow tells it how to store it as an object, where as the first example it doesn't know what the delegate type is.

The question is, any way to short hand it so I don't have to declare the variables outside of the dictionary. Something like

`delegate<ABC>(object val){return "blah1"}`

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a custom delegate like that. Simply use  [`System.Func<T,TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,Func<object,object>> 
{
  {"Blah", x => "Blah",},
  {"Blah2", x => "Blah2"}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you define your dictionary like this `Dictionary<string,ABC>` then you can do:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, ABC> 
   {
      {"key1", delegate (object obj) { return "blah"; }}
   };
```

Or you can use lambda statements:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, ABC> {{"key1", obj => "blah" }};
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are all `ABC` instances you can specify the dictionary value type more precisely:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string,ABC>()
{
    {"key1",delegate(object val){return "blah";}},
    {"key2",delegate(object val){return "blah2";}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, you can use lambdas to accomplish this:

```
private delegate object ABC(object a);

private Dictionary<string, ABC> dict = new Dictionary<string, ABC>
    {
        { "key1", a => "blah1" },
        { "key2", a => { return "blah2"; } }
    };
```

Note that I've expressed the same functionality two different ways. The lambda used for key1 is simplified and has the same meaning as the lambda for key2. `a` will be assigned the `object` value that's passed into your delegate.